In angular Rxjs catchError fails with TypeError
I am trying to send post request to create/update user. When I get 400 response, the catchError function fails with

TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected.
You can provide an Observable, Promise, ReadableStream, Array,
AsyncIterable, or Iterable.
at createInvalidObservableTypeError (throwUnobservableError.js:2:12)
at innerFrom (innerFrom.js:37:11)
at catchError.js:10:29

My Error response object is,
{
  "isSuccess": false,
  "message": "User with same email already registered.",
  "responseObject": {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "" 
  }
}

My code is,
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

import { environment } from '../../../../environments/environment';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CreateUser {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  createIcUser(request: object) {
    return this.http
      .post<any>(`${environment.URL}/api/users`, request)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  updateIcUser(id: string, request: object) {
    return this.http
      .put<any>(`${environment.URL}/api/users/${id}`, request)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  private handleError(errorRes: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.log(errorRes)
    let errors = { title: errorRes.error.title, details: [] };
    if (
      typeof errorRes.error.errors === 'object' &&
      errorRes.error.errors !== null &&
      Object.keys(errorRes.error.errors).length > 0
    ) {
      errors.details = Object.keys(errorRes.error.errors).map((field) => ({
        field,
        message: errorRes.error.errors[field].join(', '),
      }));
    } else {
      if (errorRes.error.isSuccess === false) {
        errors.title = 'Server Error';
        errors.details.push({
          field: 'error',
          message: errorRes.error.message,
        });
      }
    }

    return throwError(
      () =>
        errors || {
          title: 'An unknown error occurred!',
          details: [
            {
              field: 'error',
              message: errorRes.error.message,
            },
          ],
        }
    );
  }
}

My subscription code is,
let updateUserObs: Observable<any>;
    if (!this.isEditMode) {
      updateUserObs = this.createUserService.createIcUser(
        this.getProperties({ isEditMode: false })
      );
    } else {
      updateUserObs = this.createUserService.updateIcUser(
        this.guid,
        this.getProperties({ isEditMode: true })
      );
    }

    this.subscription = updateUserObs.subscribe({
      next: (resData) => {
        this.selectedIcUser.clear();
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/users'], {
          state: {
            id: this.selectedCompany.company.id,
            success: true,
            isEditMode: this.isEditMode,
          },
        });
      },
      error: (errors) => {
        this.showErrorModal = true;
        this.errorData = errors;
        console.error('from subscription', errors);
      },
    });

What wrong with my code. Earlier, it was working fine. But suddenly I am getting this error.

@SwithDwayne your code works fine, please replicate the issue in this stackblitz and share back!

you may not always reach the throwError return.  You should check: if (errorRes.error) { if (errorRes.error.title) {...   Before trying to get errorRes.error.title  It may also help to debug if you pass the operation being called (method name or something like that) into the handleError function to log.

Are you sure you want to return an observable (using throwError) from the catchError operator? I think you should not return an observable instead return data that is expected when an API call fails for some reason. Try removing throwError and return some data (i.e. not an observable)
